# if condition is not validate my values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying (click on GET) to take values not equal to null condition is satisfied, then append row to final table, but firstly its taking true for empty values. How to fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a='';
 var b='';
 var c='';
 var d='';
 $('#getrow').click(function(){
 a = $('#empname').val();
 b = $('#age option:selected').val();
 c = $('#gender option:selected').val();
 d = $('#salary option:selected').val();

 if(a!=null && b!=null && c!=null && d!=null ){
  alert('Passed');
  //alert(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d);
   $('#final').append('<tr height=\"25\"><td>'+a+'</td><td>'+b+'</td><td>'+c+'</td><td>'+d+'</td></tr>');

  $('#empname').val(' ');
  $('#age').val(' ');
  $('#gender').val(' ');
  $('#salary').val(' ');
 }
  else{
  alert('Failed');
  }
 

 });
 });
```

```css
table,tr,th,td{
      border:1px solid #dddddd;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
 .td-bg{
 background:#006597;
 color:#fff;
 opacity:0.7;
 cursor:pointer;
 }
 .block-header{
 background:#006597;
 color:#fff;
 
 }
 .block-header th{
 text-align:center;
 }
 .active{
 background:#006597;
 color:#fff;
 }
 .addrow{
 width:10%;
 height:100px;
 background:#006597;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 line-height:100px;
 cursor:pointer;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:45%; float:left;" id="table-txt">
      <tr height="25" class="block-header">
        <th width="25%">Name</th>
        <th width="25%">Age</th>
        <th width="25%">Gender</th>
        <th width="25%">Salary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr height="25">
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="empname" placeholder="EMP Name"/></td>
        <td><select style="width:100%;" id="age"><option disabled selected>Select Age</option><option>20+</option></select></td>
        <td><select style="width:100%;" id="gender"><option disabled selected>Select Gender</option><option>Male</option><option>Female</option></select></td>
        <td><select style="width:100%;" id="salary"><option disabled selected>Select Salary</option><option>4LPM+</option><option>5LPM+</option></select></td>
      </tr>
       </table>
   <div class="addrow" id="getrow">GET RECORD</div>
   <table style="width:45%; float:right;" id="final">
      <tr height="25" class="block-header">
        <th width="25%">Name</th>
        <th width="25%">Age</th>
        <th width="25%">Gender</th>
        <th width="25%">Salary</th>
      </tr>

      
      
      </table>
```

Comment: Always will be different than null!!!

Comment: `.val()` never returns null. Protip: `console.log(a, typeof a)` and check what values you really get when the fields are empty.

Comment: You check the wrong thing. Your variables will always be non-null, as you set them to ''. You should check if(a !== '' && ...).

Comment: Thanks Its Working Fine

Comment: @enguerranws your reasoning is incorrect. The variables are all reassigned... but it is true they won't be null

Comment: You are not explicitly settling values for the options. Set value="" for "Select Age" and other default options and set value attribute for other options that carries the value you want it to.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes they're all reassigned to an empty string, which is non-null.

Comment: @charlietfl And then they're assigned to, e.g. : $('#empname').val();, which will always return a string (empty or not). So in all case, he has to check for something that is not an empty string. I don't see in what way this reasoning is incorrect ?

Answer (score 0):

change from `a!=nul`
to

```
if (a.trim()) {
    // is not empty or whitespace
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a='';
 var b='';
 var c='';
 var d='';
 $('#getrow').click(function(){
 a = $('#empname').val();
 b = $('#age option:selected').val();
 c = $('#gender option:selected').val();
 d = $('#salary option:selected').val();

 if(a.trim() && b.trim() && c.trim() && d.trim()){
  alert('Passed');
  //alert(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d);
   $('#final').append('<tr height=\"25\"><td>'+a+'</td><td>'+b+'</td><td>'+c+'</td><td>'+d+'</td></tr>');

  $('#empname').val(' ');
  $('#age').val(' ');
  $('#gender').val(' ');
  $('#salary').val(' ');
 }
  else{
  alert('Failed');
  }
 

 });
 });
```

```css
table,tr,th,td{
      border:1px solid #dddddd;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
 .td-bg{
 background:#006597;
 color:#fff;
 opacity:0.7;
 cursor:pointer;
 }
 .block-header{
 background:#006597;
 color:#fff;
 
 }
 .block-header th{
 text-align:center;
 }
 .active{
 background:#006597;
 color:#fff;
 }
 .addrow{
 width:10%;
 height:100px;
 background:#006597;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 line-height:100px;
 cursor:pointer;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:45%; float:left;" id="table-txt">
      <tr height="25" class="block-header">
        <th width="25%">Name</th>
        <th width="25%">Age</th>
        <th width="25%">Gender</th>
        <th width="25%">Salary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr height="25">
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="empname" placeholder="EMP Name"/></td>
        <td><select style="width:100%;" id="age"><option disabled value='' selected>Select Age</option><option>20+</option></select></td>
        <td><select style="width:100%;" id="gender"><option disabled  value='' selected>Select Gender</option><option>Male</option><option>Female</option></select></td>
        <td><select style="width:100%;" id="salary"><option disabled  value='' selected>Select Salary</option><option>4LPM+</option><option>5LPM+</option></select></td>
      </tr>
       </table>
   <div class="addrow" id="getrow">GET RECORD</div>
   <table style="width:45%; float:right;" id="final">
      <tr height="25" class="block-header">
        <th width="25%">Name</th>
        <th width="25%">Age</th>
        <th width="25%">Gender</th>
        <th width="25%">Salary</th>
      </tr>

      
      
      </table>
```

Comment: Its Not Working check with only value in text box then click on get its passed but it is not valid

Comment: try it know please :) i fixed it